# Inverting exponentiation modulo a prime

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Suppose $p$ is an odd prime, $g$ is a primitive root of $p$, where $i<p$ is any integer, and $w(i) = g^i \bmod p = k$.

Note that if $i \neq j$, then $w(i) \neq w(j)$, so the map is in principle invertible.

For a given k, is there a general method for finding i? All solutions I've seen have been basically trial and error, with some clever tricks to narrow the search space if i and k happen to be certain values.

Comment: what you are asking is the Discrete Log Problem. There are methods to solve it but none of them are "efficient" in terms of time complexity.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that had a name. Wikipedia has a nice discussion of it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm  Could you make an answer of this, that I could accept?

Comment: it's actually $i\not\equiv j\bmod {p-1}$